# Displaying images in marker popup fails

Tags: leaflet, popup, markers

I would like to display images in a marker popup but I get the following error:

[image]

The image does display when I write:

```
var picURL2 = 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
    imageBounds = [
        [55.1, 11.6],
        [55.0, 11.74644]
    ];
L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
```

But when I try to add it in a marker popup like so:

```
var picURL2 = 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg';

shelter1.bindPopup("<img src=" + picURL2 + "/>");
```

, I get the 404 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add extra quotes around the src value:

```js
shelter1.bindPopup("<img src='" + picURL2 + "'/>");
```

(note the single quotes `'` before and after the closing/opening string double quotes `"`)

Live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/QxqvzaIgmONlCo0jirHy?p=preview

Comment: Thx, it worked :) The images is quite large. Even when I zoom out it still takes up the entire screen. Is there a way to adjust the image inside the popup? I've tried adding "maxWidth: 200" inside the popup, but that just makes the popup smaller and not the image.

Comment: Set a `class` on the `<img>` tag and set a CSS rule on it for example. Feel free to look for resources on Stack Overflow or asking a new question there should you need further help.